# Python: Modifying XLSM-sheet without loosing VBA scripts or shapes on other sheets

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to modify an existing XLSM file, but:

- I need to keep the VBA-Scripts
- I need to keep the shapes (aka my "buttons" to trigger the scripts)

---

Further information:

- So far I used openpyxl (but am open to other modules)
- **I want to modify sheet_1 only - it contains only data**
- **sheet_2 contains shapes as buttons** with VBA-macros behind them
- sheet_3 to sheet_n contain more data without any shapes/linked scripts.

---

I managed to keep the vba scripts within the XLSM file by using the parameter "keep_vba", but it still deletes any shapes in the workbook. *And since the shapes are used as buttons, I cannot delete them.*

My code currently looks like follows.

```
 from openpyxl import load_workbook

 workbook = load_workbook(filename=insert_file, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
 import_sheet = workbook["sheet_1"]
 row_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

 # get first empty row based on the key-column (=A)
 empty_row_index = None
 for i in range(1, 500, 1):  
    if import_sheet['A'+str(i)].value is None:
        empty_row_index = i
    break

 for i, val in enumerate(row_array):   # insert row
     import_sheet.cell(row=empty_row_index, column=i+1).value = val

 workbook.save(insert_file)
```

Any help / suggestions are welcome.

Comment: openpyxl does currently not support any form controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html) can do what I want - it doesn't specify it in their documentation, but it works nevertheless. The following code snippet opens an xlsm file,  inserts data into a cell and overwrites the workbook while keeping both macros and shapes/"buttons".

```
pip install xlwings
```

---

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(r'C:\path\to\file\file.xlsm')
sht = wb.sheets['sheet_1']
sht.range('A5').value = 'Foo 1'
wb.save(r'C:\path\to\file\file.xlsm')  # full path overwrites file without prompt

# optional to close the appearing excel window
app = xw.apps.active  
app.quit()
```